# Partial differential equation, known solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Knowing that any solution of $y \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} + 2 \frac{\partial  u}{\partial y} = \frac{2}{x}$ is of the form $u(x,y) = \frac{\varphi(x) + y^2}{xy} + \psi(x)$,

where $\varphi, \ \psi $ are $C^2$,

find the solution of

$(1) \ \ y \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} + 2 \frac{\partial  u}{\partial y} = \frac{2}{x}, \ u(x,x)=g(x)$

and of

$(2) \ \ y \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} + 2 \frac{\partial  u}{\partial y} = \frac{2}{x}, \ u(y^3, y)=g(y)$.

Here $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a given function.

I'm having problems solving this.

I've solved a similar problem $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \ u(4,y)=g(y)$, ($g$ is given) where the solution was $u(x,y)=\varphi(y+x^2)$ and I just plugged $\varphi$ to the equation: $\varphi(y+16)=u(4,y)=g(y), \ \ \varphi(y)=g(y-16), \ \ u(x,y)=g(x^2+y-16)$.

But here it doesn't seem to work. Could you explain to me how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: is this two different problems ((1) and (2)) or must both conditions be satisfied simultaneously?

Comment: These are two different problems. I'll edit the question to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a second order equation. The general solution depends on two arbitrary functions ($\phi$ and $\psi$.) If you impose only one condition, you will get infinite answers depending on one arbitrary function. Consider (1). You want
$$
u(x,x)=\frac{\phi(x)+x^2}{x^2}+\psi(x)=g(x).
$$
You can choose $\psi$ arbitrarily and let
$$
\phi(x)=x^2(g(x)-\psi(x)-1).
$$

On the other hand, if you impose both conditions (1) and (2), you will get a system of two equations with the two unknowns $\phi$ and $\psi$, and you will find (in most cases) a unique solution $u$.

Comment: I see. Thank you a lot!